# Operator Overloading C++ for + operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am currently learning how to do operator overloading in C++, i found some codes online that works when it is run below.

```cpp
class Complex {
 private:
  int real, imag;

 public:
  Complex(int r = 0, int i = 0) {
    real = r;
    imag = i;
  }

  // This is automatically called when '+' is used with
  // between two Complex objects
  Complex operator+(Complex const &obj) {
    Complex res;
    res.real = real + obj.real;
    res.imag = imag + obj.imag;
    return res;
  }
  void print() { cout << real << " + i" << imag << endl; }
};

int main() {
  Complex c1(10, 5), c2(2, 4);
  Complex c3 = c1 + c2;  // An example call to "operator+"
  c3.print();
}
```

However when i tried a similar structure, i received the following error : no default constructor found and << error which i am not familiar with.

```cpp
class Chicken {
 private:
  int i;
  int k;
  int s;
  int total = 0;

 public:
  Chicken(int index, int kentucky, int sign) {
    i = index;
    k = kentucky;
    s = sign;
  }
  Chicken operator+(Chicken obj) {
    Chicken Chicky;
    Chicky.total = i + obj.i;
    return Chicky;
  }
};

int main() {
  Chicken P(1, 2, 3);
  Chicken U(2, 2, 2);
  Chicken W = P + U;

  cout << W;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNXnV.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Below](https://onlinegdb.com/bG52W_Fdw) is the corrected example. First, you were getting the error because inside `operator+` you were default constructing an object of Chicken type but your class doesn't have any default constructor. The **solution** is to add the default constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
class Chicken{
    //needed for cout<<W; to work
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Chicken &rhs);
    private:
      int i = 0;
      int k = 0;
      int s = 0;
      int total = 0; 

    public:

    

    //default constructor 
    Chicken() = default;
    
    
    //use constructor initializer list instead of assigning inside the body
    Chicken(int index, int kentucky, int sign): i(index), k(kentucky), s(sign){

        //i = index;
        //k = kentucky;
        //s = sign;
    }
    Chicken operator + (Chicken obj){
        Chicken Chicky;//this needs/uses default constructor
        Chicky.total = i + obj.i;
        return Chicky;
    }
   
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Chicken &rhs)
{
    os << rhs.i << rhs.k << rhs.s << rhs.total ;
    return os;
}
int main(){
    
   
    
    Chicken P(1,2,3); //this uses parameterized constructor
    Chicken U(2,2,2); //this uses parameterized constructor
    Chicken W = P+U;  //this uses overloaded operator+
    
    std::cout << W;   //this uses oveloaded operator<<
    
}
```

Second, you were using the statement `cout<<W;` but without overloading `operator<<`. For `std::cout<< W;` to work you will need to overload `operator<<` as i have shown in the above code.

You can check out the working example [here](https://onlinegdb.com/bG52W_Fdw).

Third, you can/should use **constructor initializer list** instead of assigning values inside the body of the constructor as shown above.

Comment: But why does the example code have a parameterized constructor but the obj created in the operate + does not reference to a default constructor but the parameterized constructor instead?

Comment: @Chicken The object named `chicky` that you create inside `operator+`'s body uses default constructor. While the objects named `P` and `U` that you create inside the `main()` are created using parameterized constructor because you are passing arguments explicitly. Check out the comments that i have added after each statement where an object is created.

Comment: Thanks! but i actually was asking about Class Complex codes, in that code, the obj Complex res; seems to be calling the parameterized constructor, why is that so?

Comment: @Chicken The parametrized constructor provides default values for its arguments, and therefore can be used as a default constructor. `Complex(int i = 0, int r = 0) { ... }` is a constructor where you may, but do not have to, provide values for `i` and `r`.

Comment: @Chicken This is because that constructor have default arguments(for all of its parameters). And so that same constructor can be used without passing any arguments. For this reason, what you're calling a parameterized constructor is actually considered a default constructor. The definition of default constructor is as follows: *A default constructor is a constructor that either has no parameters, or if it has parameters, all the parameters have default values.*